# Series of pie charts with always some colors of same labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have a panda dataframe and I want to generate one pie chart for every 'Kanton' with the frequencies in the values of 'Kat'. Not every 'Kat' occurs in every 'Kanton'. How could I do it to get always the same colors for the values in 'kat'?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Kanton': ['AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH'],
           'Kat': [1,4,5,6,1,4,2,3,3,3,2,5,1]})

kantone=df['Kanton'].unique()

for i in kantone:
   print(i)
   df_n=df.loc[df['Kanton'] == i, 'Kat'].value_counts()

   print(df_n)

   #define data
   data = df_n
   labels = df_n.index.values

   #plot
   plt.pie(data, labels = labels, autopct='%.0f%%')
   plt.title("Kanton " + i)
   plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a color to ech Kanton:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'Kanton': ['AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH'],
           'Kat': [1,4,5,6,1,4,2,3,3,3,2,5,1]})

colors = sns.color_palette("bright", len(df['Kat'].unique()))

kantone = df['Kanton'].unique()
for i in kantone:
    print(i)
    df_n = df.loc[df['Kanton'] == i, 'Kat'].value_counts()
    data = df_n
    labels = df_n.index.values

    plt.pie(data, labels=labels, colors=[colors[k-1] for k in labels], autopct='%.0f%%')
    plt.title("Kanton " + i)
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]